# Gremlin lower case / upper case

Tags: gremlin

Based on the [Modern Graph](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/images/tinkerpop-modern.png),

When I do a between search for a name, it seems to be case sensitive

```
gremlin> g.V().has("name", between("m", "mz")).values("name")
==>marko
gremlin> g.V().has("name", between("M", "Mz")).values("name")
gremlin>
```

I looked up but did not find a `lower()` or `upper()`, what I am trying to do is lower(x) == lower(y) so that the above becomes case in-sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

You could `or()` the required conditions together:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.addV('person').property('name','Marvin')
==>v[13]
gremlin> g.addV('person').property('name','Marko')
==>v[15]
gremlin> g.V().or(has("name", between("Marko", "N")),has("name", between("marko", "n")))
==>v[1]
==>v[13]
==>v[15]
gremlin> g.V().or(has("name", between("Marko", "Markoz")),has("name", between("marko", "markoz")))
==>v[1]
==>v[15]
```

Just a warning - this approach works, but different graphs will treat this type of query differently. I don't know that all will optimize this type of query. If you're just experimenting on a small graph, then this approach might be fine, but you might not see the performance you want on a large graph depending on the traversal.

Comment: yea but problem if db has name = "Marko"
so `between("Marko", "Markoz")` would be my starts with query right? so OR wont work there

Comment: sorry, i don't follow what you're saying. why doesn't OR work here? honestly, it sounds as though you should choose a database that has better text search support. this approach is a silly little workaround for really simple cases.

Comment: Yes I understand your point, OR will work. BUT If name is "StackOverFlow", and if the user types "Stackoverflow", having two OR conditions won't work.

Also I understand the real solution is to go for a Graph DB that supports full text search.

Comment: i see what you mean now. I don't have a good solution for that with this workaround.